# Are there any indexing solutions for Solana

Tags: scalability, index, query

Are there any indexers for the Solana blockchain, and what are the main differences between them?

Comment: "indexer" is a pretty nebulous term.  can you elaborate _what_ you intend to index? also if you're looking for a service or some infrastructure that you can run yourself?

Comment: @trent.sol currently I'm looking for already existing solutions, both an infrastructure or a service are interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you define the question a bit more? Most people who want to index run a Validator and will use something like the Geyser plugin.

https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins

Comment: this should be a comment on the OP, not an answer